# How do I add KSP plugin to android project gradle?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-symbol-processing

#### My aim is to add the KSP plugin to gradle as stated in the question heading.

just go through the line below each `//from quickstart` comments and you'll see all the error origins.

To add the dependencies I referred the [Kotlin KSP quickstart documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-quickstart.html).

Now, the code might not be an exact replica of the one from the docs because that didn't work and so, I attempted some failed changes to try and make it work.

---

build.gradle(app/module) -

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    //from quickstart
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cryptile"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    def room_version = "2.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    //what I want to implement
    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    //from quickstart
    implementation 'com.google.devtools.ksp:symbol-processing-api:1.6.10-1.0.2'
}
```

build.gradle(project) -

```
//from quickstart
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
    //from quickstart
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.21' apply false
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

settings.gradle -

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "CRYPTILE"
include ':app'
```

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: you can have a look at https://insert-koin.io/docs/setup/ka_1.0/

Comment: @avinash Dead link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KSP guides failed to mention where to reference your processor. Use `META-INF` resource directory to reference your processor processor in your processormodule:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/services/com.google.devtools.ksp.processing.SymbolProcessorProvider
```

In this file you reference your `ProcessorProvider`:

`com.my.package.processor.MySymbolProcessorProvider`

This is important step in order your processor provider be recognized and later instantiate the actual processor.

If your dependencies setup are not in place please read further here https://medium.com/@nikoladespotoski/hands-on-google-ksp-c0508d623863

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to add ksp in android `(version: giraffe)` gradle library:

- First, click in `build.gradle(project)` and add `[ id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.10-1.0.9" apply false ]` in `plugin {}`
- Next, click in `build.gradle(module)` to add this line `[ id("com.google.devtools.ksp") ] in plugin{}`. Then, implement ksp in dependencies block:

  ```
    //To use Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP)
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")
  ```

The version of ksp belongs the room that you use.
Thanks for reading!.

Comment: How to add KSP in Android studio iguana  and gradle.build.ktx (fully kotlin project)